# Is there a way to add back and forward menu item as buttons on a tool bar Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

There are Back and Forward commands in the Go menu in Visual Studio Code.

Is there a way to add these commands as buttons?

Questions about software developer tools are permitted. If you down vote or click close than please leave a comment for those actions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin called "Back and Forward button" that does the trick here, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=grimmer.vscode-back-forward-button